# sql skip rows that contains string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I need to skip rows that may contain text

Example: I have table `OUTSTANDING` and my fields are given below.

```
INVOICENO 
AB1       
111
ZX3
```

I need to skip rows contain `AB1` and `ZX3` and select the row that contain `111`

I have tried this query

```
"SELECT * FROM [INT]..OUTSTANDING WHERE INVOICENO NOT LIKE '%[a-z,-]%'";
```

Comment: You want only numeric values?

Comment: I need to select those rows that contain numeric values only.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2012 and have CLR enabled, check the TRY_PARSE function.

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
"SELECT * FROM [INT]..OUTSTANDING WHERE NOT INVOICENO LIKE '%[0-9]%'";
```

or

```
...where INVOICENO not like '%[a-z]%'
```

unless more advanced regex is required....
source: http://www.sqllion.com/2010/12/pattern-matching-regex-in-t-sql/

Answer (score 1):

```
Select *
FROM [INT]..OUTSTANDING 
WHERE IsNumeric(INVOICENO ) = 1 
And INVOICENO Is Not NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE ISNUMERIC(INVOICENO) = 1
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try following mothods:

Method 1:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [INT]..OUTSTANDING
WHERE InvoiceNo IS NOT NULL
    AND ISNUMERIC(InvoiceNo)=1
```

Mehod 2:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [INT]..OUTSTANDING 
WHERE InvoiceNo IS NOT NULL
  AND INVOICENO NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```